# completion of one promise, before starting the next, in a long list

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, chaining

I discovered javascript promises recently.  An advertised benefit is clean nesting by chaining then clauses.

My code works as expected, but nesting grows just as ugly as when I used callbacks.  Is there a better way to use chaining of then to remove all this nesting?  Note I need task n to complete before anything in task n+1 can start.

The very simple fixed example

```
'use strict';

function P1() {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log("starting 1")

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("done 1")
            resolve();
        }, 100)
    })
}

function P2() {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log("must start 2 only after 1 is done")

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("done 2")
            resolve();
        }, 50)
    })
}

function P3() {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log("must start 3 only after 3 is done")

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("done 3")
            resolve();
        }, 10)
    })
}

console.log("this works, but if list was long, nesting would be terribly deep");
// start 1, done 1, start 2, done 2, start 3, done 3.
P1().then(() => {
    P2().then(() => {
        P3()
    })
})
```

Based on the feedback I should have done

```
P1().then(() => {
    return P2()
}).then(() => {
    return P3()
}).catch(() => { console.log("yikes something failed" )})
```

The real code receives an array of stuff to process sequentially.
The suggested format above appears suitable only when the sequence of steps is specified as code.   Seems like there should some kind of Promise.do_these_sequentialy, rather than my code constructing the promise chain explicitly. As follows:

```
'use strict';


function driver(single_command) {
    console.log("executing " + single_command);

    // various amounts of time to complete command
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("completed " + single_command);
            resolve()
        }, Math.random()*1000)
    })
}

function execute_series_of_commands_sequentialy(commands) {
    var P = driver(commands.shift());

    if (commands.length > 0) {
        return P.then(() => { return execute_series_of_commands_sequentialy(commands) })
    } else {
        return P
    }
}

execute_series_of_commands_sequentialy([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]).then(() => {
    console.log("test all done")
})
```

Comment: This really comes into play with the web crypto api.  For example, if you want to create a key that can be used on a page, but you can't allow any encrypt/decrypt to take place until the key is created, you run into a catch 22.  The importKey function is async, and it's difficult to make sure the key is created before allowing an encrypt or decrypt to take place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
P1()
.then(() => P2())
.then(() => P3())
```

You can make your code more flat.
Also [explicit construction is an antipattern](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html#the-explicit-construction-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood how Promises work. You can chain return values as well as Promise instances and pass them further along the chain:

```
P1()
.then(() => P2())
.then(() => P3())
```

There's no need to nest them.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like how this format looks and is what I use

```
foo(){
  P1().then(()=>{
    return P2();
  }).then(()=>{
    return P3();
  }).catch((err)=>{
    //handle errors
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at async/await that greatly simplifies the writing of promises.

[JavaScript’s Async/Await Blows Promises Away](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9)

Basically, it consists in writing async functions like sync code:

```js
async function P(number) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log("starting "+number)

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("done "+number)
            resolve();
        }, 800)
    })
}

/* Or the ES6 version :
  const P = async (number) => new Promise((resolve) => { ... })
*/

async function run(){
   await P(1)
   await P(2)
   await P(3)
   
   console.log("All done!")
}

run()
```